# How to do SVM classification to time series data sets in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, classification, svm

I have some current signals over a period of time. Depending on this signals we can know if our system is working as its supposed to or if it's crashed and deciding the type of the fault.

I have a problem with dealing with time series data in a SVM classification in python

I already did the clustering with K-Means to find out how many patterns I have. Now what I want to do is the following : If I have a new current signal input I'll be able to decide in which cluster its belong.

An example of my data set is in the image bellow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWTkc.png)

I thought of using SVM classification but I don't know how to do it in the case of time series data.

Can you please help me with that or tell me if there is other way to acheive my goal?

***Edit:***

for my data I have multiple .csv files, each file contains the recording of current data at a time instance. For example :

File 1 : the recording of 100 value of current starts at 01/01/2020 06:54:54 for 2 seconds (1 recording every 0.02 second)

File 2 : the recording of 100 value of current starts at 01/01/2020 08:40:42 for 2 seconds (1 recording every 0.02 second)
....

I used this code to import all my data in a dataframe

```
file_list= glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.csv")
main_dataframe= pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(file_list[0], delimiter= ';'))
main_dataframe['Current '].values.tolist()
Data=list()
for i in range (0,len(file_list)):
     data=pd.read_csv(file_list[i], delimiter= ';')
     Data.append(data['Current '].values.tolist())
Current=np.array(Data)
X_train = TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance().fit_transform(Current)
```

I get this after scaling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cp5G.png)

For the clustering i used the code bellow

```
# Soft-DTW-k-means
print("Soft-DTW k-means")
sdtw_km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=3,
                           metric="softdtw",
                           metric_params={"gamma": .01},
                           verbose=True,
                           random_state=seed)
y_pred3 = sdtw_km.fit_predict(X_train)
```

After that I export my result to .csv files and I added a column to the files with the cluster number

Thank you !

Comment: make a descriptor where each dimension is one instant of time, then feed this to the SVM. But if you already have the centers of the clusters, why do you want SVM? just compute the distance to each cluster center and assign the value of the closest.

Comment: Yes I already did the k-means clustering but I don't know how to assign the cluster to a new data set depending on the distance to each cluster center. I used the soft DTW k-means to do my clustering

Comment: can you please post some code? post the data in the image as python data, so we can see how are you using this data. then post the code you used to generate the kmeans clusters